# functions s.t. $\lim_{\delta\to0} \frac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta^2}$ exists

Tags: calculus, limits

Trying to draw generality from derivative definition. Are there such functions that $\lim_{\delta\to0} \frac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta^2}$ exists? or more generally

$$\lim_{\delta\to0} \frac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta^n}$$ exists?

similarly for Riemann sums is it possible to have function s.t. $\sum f(x_k)\delta^2$ where $x_k\in[a,b]$ or more generally $\sum f(x_k)\delta^n$

Comment: There are such functions ($f(x)=exp(x)$ for instance). I suppose your question is rather how to charaterize those 'super-differentiable' functions ?

Comment: @Evargalo: Are you saying $\lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{e^{\delta} - 1}{\delta^2}$ exists?  Or did you mean some other function?

Comment: @Evargalo : Yes, for example are they unique? what would the chain rule or superintegration techniques be like for them?

Comment: 'super-differentiable' functions are constant, as my answer below shows. Very, very super....

Comment: Do you want the above to hold at *some* $x$ or at *every* $x$? That makes quite a lot of difference.

Comment: I commented too fast, as noted by Matthew and Fred $exp$ is not such a function. Sorry !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(y):=(y-x)^{\alpha+n}$$ with $\alpha\ge0$ is an example, as

$$\lim_{\delta\to0}\frac{(x+\delta-x)^{\alpha+n}-(x-x)^{\alpha+n}}{\delta^n}=\lim_{\delta\to0}\delta^{\alpha}.$$

But if you require the property to hold at any $x$, only the null function $f(y):=0$ is possible.

Comment: I assume you meant "But if you require the property to hold for all 
x"

Comment: @Arjang: you are right.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $\lim_{\delta\to0} \frac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta^2}$ exists. Define: $q( \delta):=\frac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta^2}$. Then

$\delta q( \delta)=\frac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta}$.

This gives: $\frac{f(x+\delta)-f(x)}{\delta} \to 0 $ for $ \delta \to 0$.

hence $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f'(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

While Fred gave an necessary condition, a sufficient condition would be:

$f$ is two times differentiable and $f'(x)=0$.

For general $n$ an $n$-times differentiable function with $f'(x)=f^{(2)}(x)=\dots=f^{n-1}(x)=0$ would suffice.